# I need help understanding the notation and the meaning behind the Cartesian product.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, notation

I have just started studying partial differential equations from PDE by Lawrence.C Evans.
While describing the transport equation, it is mentioned that,
$u_t+b\cdot Du=0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n\times(0,\infty)$, where
$b$ is a fixed vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$,$b=(b_1,\dots,b_n)$
and $u:\mathbb{R}\times[0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ is the unknown $u=u(x,t)$.

What I don't understand is $\mathbb{R}^n\times(0,\infty)$? I know its the domain of $u$ but I don't know how to understand Cartesian product as a domain.

Comment: The [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) is just another set. The elements of $\Bbb{R}^n \times (0,\infty)$ are ordered pairs $(x,t)$ with $x\in \Bbb{R}^n$ and $t\in (0,\infty)$.

Comment: See my answer to this question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3770733/what-does-x-y-in-10-10-times-0-0-mean-multiple-of-two-domains/3771468#3771468

Comment: Are you sure you did read correctly? Shouldn't it be $u = u(x,t)$ and $u : \mathbb R^n \times (0,\infty) \to \mathbb R^n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given two sets $A$ and $B$, their Cartesian Product $A \times B$ is a new set, whose elements are ordered pairs. These ordered pairs have an element of $A$ in the first coordinate, and an element of $B$ in the second coordinate.  $A \times B$ is the set that contains *all* possible ordered pairs.  In formal language,
$$ A \times B = \{ (a,b) : a \in A , b \in B \} $$
But you are trying to understand the cartesian product as a domain. To do this, I think it's best to consider a familiar example, the *Cartesian Plane* a.k.a the *x-y plane*. Recall that this is the 2-dimensional plane is defined by points
$$(x,y)$$
where $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}$.  This can be written as
$$ \mbox{Cartesian Plane } = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} $$
and any real-valued function with this domain, $f:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, can be seen as a 3-dimensional surface over the plane.

The idea is similar for $\mathbb{R}^n \times (0,\infty)$, although it may not be easy to imagine.  For the case $n=1$, we have $\mathbb{R} \times (0,\infty)$ which is the upper half plane.  So any real-valued function can be pictured as a surface over the upper half plane